# How to store something written in a running program in Java?

Tags: java

I want to store the name and surname written in a running program, so when the program is closed and you run it again, if you click the option to Show List again it will display what was written before.

```
// program.java

package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<People> Person = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true)
        {
            System.out.println("""
                    *Death Note*
                    [1] Show List
                    [2] Write New Name
                    [3] Exit
                    Type: """);
            String izbor = input.nextLine();
            if (izbor.equals("1")) {
                for (int i = 0; i < Person.size(); i = i + 1) {
                    System.out.println(Person.get(i));
                }

            } else if (izbor.equals("2")) {
                People o = new People();
                System.out.println("Name: ");
                o.setname(input.nextLine());
                System.out.println("Surname: ");
                o.setsurname(input.nextLine());
                Person.add(o);

            } else if (izbor.equals("3")) {
                break;
            } else {
                System.err.println("D:");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then there is another java class:

```
// People.java
package com.example;

public class People {
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public People() {}
    public People(String in_name, String in_surname) {
        name = in_name;
        surname = in_surname;
    }
    public String getname(){ return name; }
    public String getsurname(){ return surname; }
    public void setname(String value) { name = value; }
    public void setsurname (String value) { surname = value; }
    public String toString() {return String.format("%s %s", name, surname); }

}
```

I use IntelliJ Idea. :)

Comment: Write the contents of the ArrayList to a file after the user provides a new name, load from the file if the user selects "Show list".

Answer (score 1):

In order for the list to be saved between separate runs of your program, you need to save the list to some permanent storage. Usually permanent storage is either a file or a database. In this answer I use a file. The file can either be a text file or a data file. A text file can be opened in an editor (like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)) and its contents are human-readable. A data file's contents are not human-readable.

The simplest solution, in my opinion, is to utilize Java's inbuilt [serialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html). In order to do this, class `People` has to implement interface `java.io.Serializable`. Note that class `java.util.ArrayList` implements interface `Serializable`.

The below code demonstrates how to integrate serialization into the code in your question.
(Notes after the code.)

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class People implements Serializable {

    /** For serializing instances of this class. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3122681927353521840L;

    private static final String FILE = "persons.dat";

    private String name;
    private String surname;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static List<People> loadList() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        File f = new File(FILE);
        if (f.isFile()) {
            try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                 ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis)) {
                return (List<People>) ois.readObject(); // Unchecked cast.
            }
        }
        else {
            return new ArrayList<People>();
        }
    }

    private static void saveList(List<People> list) throws IOException {
        if (list != null) {
            File f = new File(FILE);
            try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                 ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)) {
                oos.writeObject(list);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + surname;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        List<People> person = loadList();

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("""
                    *Death Note*
                    [1] Show List
                    [2] Write New Name
                    [3] Exit
                    Type: """);
            String izbor = input.nextLine();
            if (izbor.equals("1")) {
                for (int i = 0; i < person.size(); i = i + 1) {
                    System.out.println(person.get(i));
                }
            }
            else if (izbor.equals("2")) {
                People o = new People();
                System.out.println("Name: ");
                o.setName(input.nextLine());
                System.out.println("Surname: ");
                o.setSurname(input.nextLine());
                person.add(o);
            }
            else if (izbor.equals("3")) {
                saveList(person);
                break;
            }
            else {
                System.err.println("D:");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- In method `main` we first load the list from the file *persons.dat*.
- Before exiting the program, we save the contents of `person` to the same file.

Alternatively, using a text file to save the list involves writing more code. The below code uses [stream API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html), [NIO.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) and [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). Both the code above and the code below use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

```java
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class People {

    private static final Path PATH = Paths.get("persons.txt");
    private static final String DELIM = ";";

    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public People() {
        this(null, null);
    }

    public People(String name, String surname) {
        setName(name);
        setSurname(surname);
    }

    private static People createPeople(String line) {
        String[] parts = line.split(DELIM);
        return new People(parts[0], parts[1]);
    }

    private static List<People> loadList() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        File f = PATH.toFile();
        List<People> list = new ArrayList<>();
        if (f.isFile()) {
            try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(PATH)) {
                list = lines.map(People::createPeople)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    private static void saveList(List<People> list) throws IOException {
        if (list != null) {
            try (BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(PATH,
                                                             StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                                                             StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING,
                                                             StandardOpenOption.WRITE)) {
                for (People p : list) {
                    String line = String.format("%s%s%s%n",
                                                p.getName(),
                                                DELIM,
                                                p.getSurname());
                    bw.write(line);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + surname;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        List<People> person = loadList();

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("""
                    *Death Note*
                    [1] Show List
                    [2] Write New Name
                    [3] Exit
                    Type: """);
            String izbor = input.nextLine();
            if (izbor.equals("1")) {
                for (int i = 0; i < person.size(); i = i + 1) {
                    System.out.println(person.get(i));
                }
            }
            else if (izbor.equals("2")) {
                People o = new People();
                System.out.println("Name: ");
                o.setName(input.nextLine());
                System.out.println("Surname: ");
                o.setSurname(input.nextLine());
                person.add(o);
            }
            else if (izbor.equals("3")) {
                saveList(person);
                break;
            }
            else {
                System.err.println("D:");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make your `Person` class serializable and store the persons in a file.
Here is how to do it with a pretty similar example([link](https://www.baeldung.com/java-serialization)).

This way you would have to deal with each Person individually,
I'd suggest you'd create a `DeathNote` class. The object of `DeathNote` would include the `Person` objects.

Here in Code:

```
public static DeathNote readDeathNoteFromFile(String file){
    DeathNote dn = new DeathNote();
    try {
        File myObj = new File(file);
        if (myObj.createNewFile()) {
            System.out.println("File created: " + myObj.getName());
        } else {
            System.out.println("File already exists.");

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
            dn = (DeathNote) objectInputStream.readObject();
            objectInputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dn;
    
}
public static void writeDeathNoteToFile(String file, DeathNote dn){
    try {
        File myObj = new File(file);
        if (myObj.createNewFile()) {
            System.out.println("File created: " + myObj.getName());
        }
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file, false);
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(dn);
        objectOutputStream.flush();
        objectOutputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I added a call to read at the top of `main()`

```
String filename = "deathnote.txt";
DeathNote dn = new DeathNote();
dn=readDeathNoteFromFile(filename);
```

and I called write at the bottom(could also be called after adding a person to the list):

```
            } else if (izbor.equals("3")) {
            break;
        } else {
            System.err.println("D:");
        }
    }
    input.close();
    writeDeathNoteToFile(filename, dn);
```

DeathNote class looks like this:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DeathNote implements Serializable {
    ArrayList<People> Person;

    public DeathNote() {Person = new ArrayList<People>();}
    public void addPerson(People p) {Person.add(p);}
    public int size() {return Person.size();}
    public People get(int i){return Person.get(i);}

}
```

And People needs to implement Serializable:

```
public class People implements Serializable{
```

I'd personally suggest, that you would change the name of the list `Person` to `People`, because it represents a list of people and the class `People` to `Person`, because every object of it is a single Person.

Furthermore my compiler says, that the scanner should be closed